# Solicitar bearer token con Laravel

Tags: laravel, tokens

Hay un sitio web donde, para poder logearme, necesito generar un token.

Usando POSTMAN hago la siguiente solicitud con el método POST en el body y en raw y me genera un token con el que me puedo logear después

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, quiero replicar lo mismo en Laravel, pero no sé cómo.

```
$token = Http::withBody([
        "userName" => "felipepinojapa4snk_prj@indeedemail.com",
        "flagJson" => true
    ])->post($urlToken)->json();

    dd($token);
```

Probé con esto, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a request is not supported. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.
```

Según veo, me dice que no puedo pasar un arreglo en el body. ¿Cómo lo hago entonces?

Comment: Y si en lugar de laravel pruebas con php puro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amiguitos, aquí está la respuesta, esto me funcionó:

```
$respuestaAcceso = Http::acceptJson()->contentType('application/json-patch+json')
            ->post($urlAcceso,[
                'userName' => 'felipepinojapa4snk_prj@indeedemail.com',
                'flagJson' => true
            ])->json();

        // dd($acceso);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro, estas pasando un array, cuando debes pasar un objeto.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$token = Http::withBody((object)[
        "userName" => "felipepinojapa4snk_prj@indeedemail.com",
        "flagJson" => true
    ])->post($urlToken)->json();
```

O también

```
$logindata = new stdClass();
$logindata->userName = "felipepinojapa4snk_prj@indeedemail.com";
$logindata->flagJson= true;

$token = Http::withBody($logindata)->post($urlToken)->json();
```